# Mapping nested list using Automapper

Tags: c#, automapper

I have 3 classes `Person`, `Hobby` and `Customer`

```
public class Person {
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public List<Hobby> Hobbies {get;set;}
}

public class Hobby {
    public string Type {get;set;}
}

public class Customer {
    public string CustomerName {get;set;}
    public string TypeOfHobby {get;set;}
}
```

With the following Automapper mapping

```
CreateMap<Customer, Person>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Name, opt => opt.MapFrom(scr => src.CustomerName))

CreateMap<Customer, Hobby>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Type, opt => opt.MapFrom(scr => src.TypeOfHobby))
```

I now create a list of Persons and Customers

```
var persons = new List<Person>()
var customers = new List<Customers>(){
    new(){
        CustomerName = "john doe",
        TypeOfHobby = "reading"
    },
    new(){
        CustomerName = "jane doe",
        TypeOfHobby = "sports"
    }
}
```

I want to be able to map from the customers list to the persons list as follows:

```
[
    {
        "name": "john doe",
        "hobbies": [
            {
                "type": "reading"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "jane doe",
        "hobbies": [
            {
                "type": "sports"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I have tried the following:

```
var mappedPersons = _mapper.Map<List<Person>>(customers)
```

but I'm not sure how to do the mapping for the `Hobbies` inside each `mappedPersons`

Answer (score 1):

I think, in your case, just constructing a new list will do the job,

```
CreateMap<Customer, Person>()
     .ForMember(dest => dest.Name, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.CustomerName))
     .ForMember(dest => dest.Hobbies, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => new List<Hobby>
     {
         new Hobby
        {
            Type = src.TypeOfHobby
        }
     }));
```

Answer (score 0):

For your scenario, you need a [Custom Value Resolver](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Custom-value-resolvers.html#custom-value-resolvers) for mapping the `Hobbies` property in the destination class.

```cs
CreateMap<Customer, Person>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Name, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.CustomerName))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Hobbies, opt => opt.MapFrom((src, dest, destMember, ctx) =>
    {
        List<Hobby> hobbies = new List<Hobby>();
        hobbies.Add(ctx.Mapper.Map<Hobby>(src));
        return hobbies;
    }));
```

[Demo @ .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/PmYJiq)